# How to simplify -a*z+a*z to 0 where "a" is an expression

Tags: simplifying-expressions, symbolic, algebraic-manipulation

Consider the following:

```
a = 1+(x+y+z+u)^10000 
(* Out[57]= 1+(u+x+y+z)^10000 *)
e = -a*z+a*z
(* Out[59]= z (-1-(u+x+y+z)^10000)+z (1+(u+x+y+z)^10000) *)
```

How can I simplify `-a*z+a*z` (assigned to `e`) to 0? The simplification is obvious.

I tried:

```
Simplify[e]
(* Out[60]= z (-1-(u+x+y+z)^10000)+z (1+(u+x+y+z)^10000) *)
FullSimplify[e]
(* Out[61]= z (-1-(u+x+y+z)^10000)+z (1+(u+x+y+z)^10000) *)
Distribute[e]
(* Out[62]= z (-1-(u+x+y+z)^10000)+z (1+(u+x+y+z)^10000) *)
```

None of it worked. The only two functions that can do that are `Expand[e]` and `Apart[e]`, both of which work for smaller expressions, but never finish for this one:

```
Apart[e]
(*
No more memory available.
Mathematica kernel has shut down.
Try quitting other applications and then retry.
*)
```

because they are expanding the `(u+x+y+z)^10000` part, which takes forever.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: Please reformat your code according to the guidelines in [meta1027](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1027/what-kind-of-input-and-output-code-styles-are-acceptable-in-se).  Doing so will encourage more people to try to answer your question.

Comment: e /. (x + y + z + u) -> t // Simplify

Answer (score 14):

`Expand` takes forever, because it is trying to expand `(u + x + y + z)^10000`.  Tell it not to.

```
Expand[e, Power[u + x + y + z, 10000]]
(* 0 *)
```

Comment: Thanks! Or in general `Expand[e, _^_]` will work too.

Comment: Well, hey, that's something I did not know about `Expand`, nifty. +1